# How to remove a specific pusipin in Bing Maps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I am developing a Windows Store App where I use the Bing Maps control. So far, I have created a method to add a pushpin for my current location. And other ones for a near places I wanna to display. All this is working OK.

However, when I try to remove the pushpin for the near placer without removing the one of my current location, I got an exception: **Collection was modified; enumaration operation may not execute**.

This is my code I am trying to implement:

```
if(this.MyBingMap.Children.Count > 0)
{
   MapUIElementCollection collection = this.MyBingMap.Children;
   foreach(var pushpin in collection)
   {
      this.MyBingMap.Children.Remove(pushpin);
   }
}
```

For the above code, the first time it works. But, for the second interection is where I got the exception.

So, does anyone know how to remove some specifics pushpins?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify the element in the collection you're looping on, it is not something you can do due to logical restriction.
Try to store the element you want to remove in another collection or array and then make a second loop to remove it.

If you have already the reference to the element you want to remove, it is even easier to remove the element since you don't have to do the first loop.

And if you want to remove all children elements, see the clear() method on the MapUIElementCollection class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846487.aspx